QCameraViewFinder (with Webcam) interfering with Qt3D (stops rendering when QCamera is started)
I've recently developed a visualization for some of my robotics work using Qt3D. The visualization is based on the Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow class and contains several STL files.
auto * layout = new QGridLayout(this);
m_view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();
m_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(m_view);
layout->addWidget(m_container,0,0);
setLayout(layout); // this is in code that subclasses QFrame
// construct scene:
m_root = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
// ... 
// set up camera
Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = m_view->camera();
camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
// ... 
m_view->setRootEntity(m_root);
m_view->show();

As part of this project I require a video feed, so I integrated QCamera from QtMultiMedia. I then use QCameraViewfinder from QtMultimediaPlugins to render the video stream.
When I start the QCamera stream I receive the video in the QCameraViewfinder, but the rendering in the Qt3DWindow stops. I get messages on the console stating "QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called" whenever I move the window. The visualization does not disappear if the viewfinder is not set on the camera.
m_camerasetup_viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
QList<QCameraInfo> camera_list = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
for (auto & camera : camera_list) {
    if (camera.description() == listCameras->currentText()) {
        m_camerasetup_camera = new QCamera(camera); break; 
    }
}
// commenting this line stops the visualization from dissapearing 
//m_camerasetup_camera->setViewfinder(m_camerasetup_viewfinder);
m_camerasetup_camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
m_camerasetup_camera->start();

I honestly have no idea why the visualization stops rendering. I have tried to google this (and have searched StackOverflow), but unfortunately have come up short. Does anybody have any idea on what may be causing this, and better, how to fix it so that I can see both the visualization and the camera feed?
Thank you in advance!
